# Inline If-Else Throws System.ArgumentException: Argument types do not match

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I have the following snippet:

```
var a = dbContext.Employees.AsQueryable();
var b = dbContext.Employees.Where(x => x.IsManager == 1);
var results = dbContext.Companies
                       .SelectMany(x => x.IsActive == 1 ? a : b)
                       .Select(x => x.Id);
```

I thought it's going to execute without any issues, but interestingly I got this error:

> fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
>             Connection id "0HLQ6AD1S5ITB", Request id "0HLQ6AD1S5ITB:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
>       System.ArgumentException: Argument types do not match
>          at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Condition(Expression test, Expression ifTrue, Expression ifFalse, Type type)
>          at System.Linq.Expressions.ConditionalExpression.Update(Expression test, Expression ifTrue, Expression ifFalse)
>          at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitConditional(ConditionalExpression node)
>          at System.Linq.Expressions.ConditionalExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
>          at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.ReplaceClauseReferences(Expression expression, IQuerySource querySource, Boolean inProjection)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.CompileAdditionalFromClauseExpression(AdditionalFromClause additionalFromClause, QueryModel queryModel)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryModelVisitor.CompileAdditionalFromClauseExpression(AdditionalFromClause additionalFromClause, QueryModel queryModel)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.VisitAdditionalFromClause(AdditionalFromClause fromClause, QueryModel queryModel, Int32 index)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryModelVisitor.VisitAdditionalFromClause(AdditionalFromClause fromClause, QueryModel queryModel, Int32 index)
>          at Remotion.Linq.Clauses.AdditionalFromClause.Accept(IQueryModelVisitor visitor, QueryModel queryModel, Int32 index)
>          at Remotion.Linq.QueryModelVisitorBase.VisitBodyClauses(ObservableCollection`1 bodyClauses, QueryModel queryModel)
>          at Remotion.Linq.QueryModelVisitorBase.VisitQueryModel(QueryModel queryModel)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.VisitQueryModel(QueryModel queryModel)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryModelVisitor.VisitQueryModel(QueryModel queryModel)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](QueryModel queryModel)
>          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](QueryModel queryModel)

I'm not sure what's wrong here, especially that this snippet works just fine with the correct results:

```
var a = dbContext.Employees.AsQueryable();
var results = dbContext.Companies
                       .SelectMany(x => a)
                       .Select(x => x.Id);
```

and this snipped alone works fine as well:

```
var b = dbContext.Employees.Where(x => x.IsManager == 1);
var results = dbContext.Companies
                       .SelectMany(x => b)
                       .Select(x => x.Id);
```

P.S. I'm using EF Core 2.2

---

**UPDATE 1**

Okay I was trying to simplify my problem with the above example but I think that wasn't a good idea.

So here is what I actually have: I have three main entities: `Post`, `Employee`, and, `WorkGroup` and three mapping entities: `EmployeeWorkGroup`, `PostEmployee`, and `PostWorkGroup`. The six entities have the following implementation:

```
class Post {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int IsGlobal { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PostEmployee> Employees { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PostWorkGroup> WorkGroups { get; set; }
}

class Employee {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

class WorkGroup {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid? ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Prefix { get; set; }
}

class EmployeeWorkGroup {
    public Guid EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public Guid WorkGroupId { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set }
    public virtual WorkGroup WorkGroup { get; set; }
}

class PostEmployee {
    public Guid EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public Guid PostId { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set }
    public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
}

class PostWorkGroup {
    public Guid WorkGroupId { get; set; }
    public Guid PostId { get; set; }
    public virtual WorkGroup WorkGroup { get; set; }
    public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
}
```

Put simply, the main purpose is to send posts to employees either directly to them (using `PostEmployee` entity), by work groups: (using `EmployeeWorkGroup` and `PostWorkGroup`), or to all employees (by setting `IsGlobal` of `Post` to 1).

I managed to do the above, now I want to fetch the employees of a given post. The challenge is that I need to collect them from the post's designated work groups (which is hierarchical) (using `EmployeeWorkGroup` and `PostWorkGroup`) and from the post's employees (using `PostEmployee` entity). If the post was sent to every one (i.e., `IsGlobal` is 1), I need to return all employees.

This is my current attempt:

```
// get all employee ids from the posts work groups
Expression<Func<Post, IEnumerable<Guid>>> postEmployeesFromWorkGroups = post =>
    allWorkGroups
        .Where(workGroup => post.WorkGroups
            .Any(postWorkGroup => workGroup.Prefix.StartsWith(postWorkGroup.WorkGroup.Prefix)))
        .SelectMany(y => y.Employees
            .Where(z => !post.Employees.Any(b => b.EmployeeId.Equals(z.EmployeeId))))
        .Select(y => y.EmployeeId)
        .Distinct();

// get all employee ids from posts' immediate employees list
Expression<Func<Post, IEnumerable<Guid>>> postEmployees = post => post.Employees.Select(x => x.EmployeeId);

// return the results
public static Expression<Func<Post, IEnumerable<Employee>>> var predicate = post => post.IsGlobal == 1
    ? allEmployees
    : allEmployees.Where(x =>
        postEmployeesFromWorkGroups.Invoke(post).Contains(x.Id) ||
        postEmployees.Invoke(post).Contains(x.Id));


db.Posts.AsExpandable().Where(x=>x.Id.Equals("some-id")).Select(predicate);
```

With out the condition, I can execute either side of the if-else flawlessly.

P.S. I'm using LinqKit.

---

**UPDATE 2**

This is the query that I get by executing the code above (I removed one side of the if else to make it work):

```
SELECT [x0].[id]
FROM [posts] AS [x]
CROSS JOIN [employees] AS [x0]
WHERE (([x].[is_deleted] <> 1) AND ([x0].[is_deleted] <> 1)) AND ([x0].[id] IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT [workGroup.Employees].[employee_id]
  FROM [work_groups] AS [x1]
  INNER JOIN [employees_work_groups] AS [workGroup.Employees] ON [x1].[id] = [workGroup.Employees].[work_group_id]
  WHERE (([x1].[is_deleted] <> 1) AND EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM [work_groups_posts] AS [postWorkGroup]
      INNER JOIN (
          SELECT [x2].*
          FROM [work_groups] AS [x2]
          WHERE [x2].[is_deleted] <> 1
      ) AS [t] ON [postWorkGroup].[work_group_id] = [t].[id]
      WHERE (([x1].[prefix] LIKE [t].[prefix] + N'%' AND (LEFT([x1].[prefix], LEN([t].[prefix])) = [t].[prefix])) OR ([t].[prefix] = N'')) AND ([x].[id] = [postWorkGroup].[post_id]))) AND NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM [employees_posts] AS [b]
      WHERE ([b].[employee_id] = [workGroup.Employees].[employee_id]) AND ([x].[id] = [b].[post_id]))
) OR [x0].[id] IN (
  SELECT [x3].[employee_id]
  FROM [employees_posts] AS [x3]
  WHERE [x].[id] = [x3].[post_id]
))
```

Comment: What is the type of `x.IsActive` ? It seems boolean and you compare it against an int. What is the point of `x.IsActive == 1 ? a : a` ? The same value is returned no matter the result of the condition

Comment: @Cid It is an int not a boolean, Yeah I know the same value, but it should work, shouldn't it?

Comment: `x.IsActive == 1 ? a: a` what is the use of checking condition here as true and false are having same statements?

Comment: @m2008m1033m you're asking people to guess what your entities and tables look like, and why a statement that looks like a no-op behaves the way it does. Is this the real code or something that "looks like" it? You're asking people to guess

Comment: Wow - `a` is a *query*, not an item or an enumerable. What do you expect that thing to do? Return all employees repeatedly, for every company? There's no way to translate this thing to SQL.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I was trying to simplify the question. I updated it the question to reflect what I'm trying to achieve. Please have a look.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos but how can the other two cases work fine?!

Comment: @m2008m1033m I suggest you explain your *real* problem, not how you think it can be solved. Eg `I want to return all employees for active companies but only managers for inactive ones`.  What would you expect the SQL query to look like?  This code is definitely wrong. Once you phrase the question properly, the answer is a lot simpler, *assuming* the entities have proper relations between them

Comment: For example `dbContext.Employees.Where(e=>e.Company.IsActive==1 || (e.Company.IsActive!=1 && e.IsManager ==1).Select(e=>e.ID)` will get you the employee IDs. `.Distinct(e=>e.Company.Id)` will get you the distinct company IDs.

Comment: @m2008m1033m none of these snippets works fine. If they even compile it's probably by accident and client-side evaluation. The only way you'd avoid duplicate results is if there's only one `Company` in the database.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I updated the question to reflect my real problem, can you please have a look at it.

Comment: @m2008m1033m I already explained what a correct query would look like. Passing one queryable inside another is simply wrong. This can't be translated to SQL and the only way it works is that EF Core 2.2 uses client-side evaluation - when it can't generate a SQL statement, it loads everything in memory and then tries to process the data locally. That's a *very* bad idea because it wastes bandwidth, RAM and CPU on the client while hiding the problems in the query.

Comment: @m2008m1033m client-side evaluation was removed in EF Core 3 so your code will probably break when you upgrade

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It's not evaluated locally, it gets executed all in the database. Care to tell me why it is a wrong idea to use a queryable inside another. Or maybe a link that explains why is it wrong?

Comment: Because it returns duplicate employees unless you only have a single company. *Nothing* connects companies and employees. Have you tried capturing the generated SQL statements with SQL Server Profiler? How many queries are executed, what do they return?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I added the generated query to the question.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It will never return duplicate employees as I'm querying the employees table itself. I pretty sure about that.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It will return duplicate employees in case I selected multiple posts using the where clause, which I'm fine with. In other words, the returned result in this case would be a list of employee lists, each corresponding to certain post.

Comment: The query and that CROSS JOIN say otherwise. The simple fact that the query is so complicated that it's unreadable is enough to prove that what you're doing is wrong. Did you notice that all combinations between posts and employees are created? That they're filtered by a *very* expensive subquery?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos In that case, can you please tell me if there is a more efficient solution to my problem?

Comment: Apparently _a_ and _b_ have different types. The _if_ does not have to be inlined. You do not need to write the query in one single statement. So you can use a normal if statement to assemble the query and then execute it.

Comment: @DanielSchmid How can they have different types? They both are of type IQueryable<Employee>. I know that I can assemble sub queries to generate a larger one. The thing is I can't do that here because the condition relies on a value that's coming from the database.

Comment: @m2008m1033m they poth have the same interface - _IQueryable_ but that does not mean it's the same type.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200273/discussion-on-question-by-m2008m1033m-inline-if-else-throws-system-argumentexcep).